# How to describe this body position?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, image-identification

How to describe the body gesture in this [image](https://www.pinterest.co.uk/pin/89649848815729673/)?

[image: statue sitting outside on a cobbled sloping path: knees bent, arms crossed over them]

<sub>(Sculpture by Anthony Gormley, photo from Teri Gidlof via Pinterest)</sub>

Is it natural to say this guy is curling up himself, with his arms holding his knees?

Are there any other terms which can be used to describe him?

Comment: Very similar question that was asked last year got this answer: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/323886/what-do-you-call-this-sitting-pose-or-position-that-sad-or-depressed-people-adop/390511#390511 (at least one of those answers might help you here)

Comment: The duplicate mentions the 'brace' position, which is possibly correct.

Comment: The link show the installation art in its full glory https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iBdz.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd give you:

**[Fetal Position](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fetal_position)**

> In this position, the back is curved, the head is bowed, and the limbs are bent and drawn up to the torso.

usually it's lying down but usually being curled up in enough.

Which brings us to number two:

**Curled into a ball**.

Which means exactly what it says.

Comment: You can see *foetal position* in the sculpture at the top of the slope in the image. However, I would say it's almost exclusively used for that lying-down position.

Comment: If you look closely at the middle region of the picture, another sculpture is ***actually*** curled in the fetal position, far behind the sculpture in the foreground! (Update: wrote and posted this at the same time as your fractionally earlier comment @Andrew Leach.)